# Проблема в шрифте, Montserrat на ПК и андроид выглядит нормально, на Safari Он меняет стиль

Tags: вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, адаптивность

Здесь как он должен выглядеть https://prnt.sc/uvzw6l, а так он отображается на айфоне 6s+ https://prnt.sc/uvzwwb
Кто сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Comment: Т.к Вы не привели [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), [приведу его за Вас](https://pastebin.com/RR3P8TWE) — в этом примере, в Safari на iOS 14.0.1 шрифт отображается корректно, ровно как и на macOS 10.15.7.

Comment: Например на iphone 6s+ стиль текста выглядит не так, а на iphone 8 все нормально, и я не совсем понимаю в чем причина.

Comment: Приведите [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Абсолютно та же проблема, но не на мобильных устройствах, а в Сафари на макбук. Сайт на тильде, шрифты подключены из библиотеки гугла, причем тоже монсеррат. Любопытная деталь - сафари отображает ту же семью шрифтов - монсеррат, но другой шрифт "montserrat alternates" вместо просто "montserrat". Может это уточнение вам хоть как-то поможет в поиске истины, буду очень благодарна, если, найдя решение, вы им поделитесь)

Answer (score 0):

Данная проблема присутствует в сафари на некоторых версиях iOS и macOS и не только со шрифтом montserrat. Попробуйте подключать не через тег link href... а скачать архив с нужным шрифтом и подключить через @font-face, чтобы настроить жирность шрифта можно сделать вот так:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 400;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url('fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Regular.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 500;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url('fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-Medium.ttf');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'Montserrat';
  font-weight: 600;
  font-display: swap;
  src: url('fonts/montserrat/Montserrat-SemiBold.ttf');
}
```